# why ECS suddenly restarts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

our example.com suddenly gives 503 service temporarily unavailable error

I check the monitor and get the following

It looks like docker container restarted for some reason, what should I check?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

as you can see `UnHealthyHostCount` jump from `0` to `2`, its the ECS services are restarted and due to some reason it still passing the health check or ALB did not yet receive success HTTP status code.

You can look into ECS Cluster

- Select cluster -> ECS service -> Event

You will see the reason for health check failure or might be restarted by the user or some other service.

[image]